# Linear velocity to arc and back

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, vectors, circles

I'm trying to calculate a direction and magnitude for simulating a rope swing. I start off with the player's position, `(x, y)` and their current velocity, `(s1, s2)`.

[image]

Next, I attach the rope to point `(a, b)`.
I know the distance of the rope, `r`, given the coordinates of the end points. Line `d` represents the arc the object would move along the circle with radius `r`. The length of `d` is equal to the magnitude of the current velocity `(s1, s2).magnitude`. Note, the original velocity could be pointing in any direction, so `d` could be clockwise or counterclockwise.

[image]

What I need to derived from all this data is a new vector, `(m,n)`:

[image]

This vector should start at `(x,y)`, point to where `d` ends, and have a length equal to the distance from `(x,y)` to where `d` ends. I'm having difficulty working out the math.

Comment: From a physicists point of view this prescription does not make sense. Equating a distance with a velocity needs some time factor to get correct units. If you want to describe the motion correctly (given initial position and velocity) you need to solve the pendulum equation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendulum_(mechanics) . This basically answers the question: where is the point after some time $t$.

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified the time aspect. This is how much the object moves in one frame. So if the object was not tethered to the hook, the resulting position would be `(x,y) + (S1,S2)`. The "corrected" position that I'm looking for puts the object at `(x,y) + (m,n)`.